# Proof of projection matrix multiplication with any vector

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, projection-matrices

Im studying Projection matrix (linear algebra) and I understood that projection matrix onto line **a** can be calculated as:

$\cfrac{a a^T}{a^T a}$

I know that multiplying any vector to this matrix calculates the projection onto the line **a**, but I want to know why.

I tried to search, but i couldn't find any help me plz

Comment: What's your definition of "the projection of $v$ onto the line **a**"?

Comment: finding a vector **p** in line **a** which is closest to vector **b**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

If $x=v+w$ with $v$ parallel to $a$ and $w$ perpendicular to $a$, then compute what your matrix does to $x$. Use that $a^T w=0$ and that $v=ka$ for some $k$.

Edit: The proof you need depends heavily on your base assumptions of what projection is.

Comment: Oh I think i can get close to it. Thx :)